# Denying access to all but one folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying write an IAM policy which denies access to all but one folder. This seems to be the exact use case written about [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html#iampolicy-example-s3homedir).

I wrote a policy that looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["folder/subfolder/*"]}}
    },
    {
       "Action":["s3:*"],
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::folder/subfolder/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

which is basically (to me at least), the exact same thing as their example.

It doesn't work.

The user is denied access to all other buckets, but this bucket he seems to have free range.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging/diagnosing issues with any kind of [IAM Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html) I highly recommend the [IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/iam-policy-simulator-guide.html) (see [Using the IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/using-iam-policy-simulator.html) for details and direct access):

> You can use the IAM policy simulator to test the effects of AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies before you commit the policies into production, and to test your existing IAM policies to verify that they have the intended effect.

The policy simulator can be a bit picky/tricky to use, but I've just verified the referenced sample policy to [Allow Users to Access a Personal "Home Directory" in Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html#iampolicy-example-s3homedir) as follows:

1. add the policy to a test IAM user
2. click the 'Simulate Policy' link right from the AWS Management Console
3. select service `Amazon S3` and the desired actions, e.g. `GetObject` (or just *Select All*)
4. enter the resources under test in S3 resource format, e.g. `arn:aws:s3:::testbucket.example.com/home/testuser/*`
5. subsequently enter variations of `aws:username` for the test, i.e. `testuser` and `anotheruser`

Incidentally it didn't work for me either at first because `anotheruser` had been part of a group that granted general S3 read access anyway, which was immediately surfaced by the IAM Policy Simulator - maybe that's the problem with your IAM configuration too?

Comment: In the end we went with a solution of just renaming the buckets and limiting the user's access, so I didn't test if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRootLevelListingOfCompanyBucket",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            ""
          ],
          "s3:delimiter": [
            "/"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListBucketIfSpecificPrefixIsIncludedInRequest",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "folder/subfolder/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToFullAccess",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/folder/subfolder/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Read the **`Sid`** in each statement to understand the action.

Comment: In the end we went with a solution of just renaming the buckets and limiting the user's access, so I didn't test if this worked.